# Объединить массивы

Tags: php

Имеются массивы выводятся в цикле

```
foreach($k as $t => $r){
$r = explode(" ", $r);
print_r($r);
}
на экране так:
Array ( [0] => 10.10.1.0 ) Array ( [0] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AB ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 10.10.1.1 ) Array ( [0] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AС ) Array ( [0] => 8 ) Array ( [0] => 10.10.1.2 ) Array ( [0] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AD) Array ( [0] => 9 )
```

Как сделать так (Объединить по 3)

```
Array( [0] => 10.10.1.0 [1] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AB [2] => 7 ) Array( [0] => 10.10.1.1 [1] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AС [2] => 8 ) Array( [0] => 10.10.1.2 [1] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AD [2] => 9 )
```

Comment: у вас `explode` всегда возвращает 1 элемент что ли? зачем он тогда нужен? разбейте исходных на группы по 3 `array_chunk($k, 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в $r получается строки лежат. Для чего их в массив преобразовывать?
Вам получается нужно массивы по 3 элемента подряд идущих, если я верно понял

```
$i = 0;
$result = [];
foreach($k as $t => $r){
    $result[floor($i/3)][$i % 3] = $r;
    $i++;
}
```

В итоге получается массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.10.1.0
            [1] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AB
            [2] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.10.1.1
            [1] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AРЎ
            [2] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.10.1.2
            [1] => FF:66:00:77:FF:AD
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Что то с кодом не то

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10.10.1.0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => FF:DD:04:74:F3:AB ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) )

Comment: а как сделать теперь чтоб условие допустим по маку было if( isset($array_1[$result[0?????]])

Comment: не понял вашего вопроса

Comment: @Kvandaik __не надо__ задавать дополнительные вопросы, напрямую не связанные с вашим, в комментариях. Создайте новый вопрос, на который вам постараются ответить.

Comment: элемент нулевого массива взять ключ [1] это как делается $result[0][1]