# Шаблон вхождение пробел

Tags: php

```
$arr_str = preg_split("( ){3}", $r); (Не работает)
```

есть строки 10.0.0.1 AA:SS:DD:FF:HH 35 10.0.0.2 AA:TT:GG:BB:CC 36

превратить в массив `Array( [0] => 10.0.0.1 [1] => AA:SS:DD:FF:HH [2] => 35 ) Array( [0] => 10.0.0.2 [1] => AA:TT:GG:BB:CC [2] => 36 )`

Comment: Вам же ответили здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897139/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b, что теперь не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем `preg_split` используйте `explode`

```
$result = explode(' ', $arr_str);
```

Comment: Тогда так  получаетсяArray ( [0] => 10.0.0.1 ) Array ( [0] =>AA:SS:DD:FF:HH ) Array ( [0] => 35 )

Comment: не может у вас так получится [0], так как все значения вернутся в 1 массив

Comment: Шаблон вхождение пробел в других языках вроде как есть шаблон по 3 пробелам и отсечка